# dynamically set per_page in django-tables2

Tags: django-tables2

Websites often allow the user to specify how many items to show per page in a paginated table.  Iwould like to do this with django-tables2.

I could add a "Show [ 5 | 10 | 50 ] per page" select box to collect a per_page parameter from the user.

However, the "Previous" and "Next" buttons in the table template are hyperlinks, with a hardcoded value for per_page, e.g.:

```
<a href="?per_page=5&page=5">Next</a>
```

I am thinking the only way to make this dynamic would be to use javascript, e.g.:

```
<span onclick="get_table_page(5)">Next</span>
```

Where the functions get_table_page() can retrieve the per_page parameter from the select box.

Is that the best way to do it?  Or is there a way without javascript?

UPDATE: No answer to the question (how to change per_page for Previous/Next page) but, as accepted answer points out, user can reload the current page with changed per_page parameter, e.g.:

```
<p>Show [ <a href="{% querystring "per_page"=5  %}">5</a>
        | <a href="{% querystring "per_page"=20 %}">20</a>
        | <a href="{% querystring "per_page"=50 %}">50</a>
        ] Items</p>
```

With thanks and best wishes

Ivan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

django-tables2 supports the `per_page` keyword argument to `table.paginate()`. If `RequestConfig` or one of the class based views is used, just adding `per_page=20` to the url will make django-tables2 re-render with 20 rows per page.

You can create urls in your custom template using the `{% querystring per_page=20 %}` tag, which should keep the sorting/filtering intact.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The documentation is very clear.  Adding or changing the per_page parameter in the url works as expected.

However, my question is about enabling the viewer to change the per_page parameter themselves in the browser.  In the default template, the Previous and Next buttons are hyperlinks, and the per-page parameters are set server-side before rendering.

Comment: Yes, the second part of my comment suggests rendering the links to change the `per_page` parameter. These would result in a reload of the page, with different numbers in the prev/next links.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow you.  Template tags are rendered on the server.  I need the user to be able to change the per_page parameter in the browser.  e.g. page loads showing 20 per page; user selects "show 50 per page"; user clicks "Next"; page loads showing next 50 items. I suppose it would be easier to make the "Show [ 5 | 10 | 50 ] items" select box a set of links, so changing the selection would reload the page.

Comment: Why is it critical to do it dynamically? If you must have a dropdown, you can also use a form to submit that to the correct url to change the `per_page` argument.

Comment: I've accepted your answer and updated the question to clarify.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to find the current querystring (with differents parameters) so I wrote in my template :

```
Show <select id="select_per_page" onchange="perPageChange($(this).val())">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select> items
```

and with a few javascript :

```
<script>
    function perPageChange(per_page)
    {
        /* per_page in querystring : replace the value in the current url */
        if (location.href.indexOf('per_page=') > 0)
            url = location.href.replace(/(per_page=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + per_page)
        else
        {
        /* per_page not in querystring */
            /* is there a parameter in querystring */
            if (location.href.indexOf('?') > 0)
                addStr = '&'
            else
                addStr = '?'
            addStr += 'per_page=' + per_page
            url = location.href + addStr
        }
        /* reload the page */
        location.href = url;
    }

    /* to select the correct option in the select */
    $('#select_per_page').val({{ table.page.object_list|length }});
</script>
```